# Creating line chart using categorical variable in r

Tags: r

Good Day,please am still new in R learning, i have been learning about chart and plot recently,but i have this data am trying to create line chart for, but cannt figure how:

[image]

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please attach the R code creating the data, not a picture. Please explain what kind of a line chart you want (there you can attach a picture, if you can draw something).

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)